# How to disable context menu for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

How do I disable the context menu behaviour for all the elements inside a  (most importantly a p5 canvas). At the moment I'm trying to disable the behaviour by disabling it off at the .

```
document.getElementById("ScriptHolder").addEventListener("contextmenu", funciton(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

where "scriptHolder" is the id of the

When I run the webpage the JS file is linked to, it throws:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Methods online of including a false item at the end of the list, as well as breaking it up into multiple lines don't work. Any help would be nice, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `function`; your code says `funciton`. That's probably why it's not working :)